# Why is 'libgnomevfs' files under /usr/include/gnome-vfs-2.0?

Tags: compiling, paths, gnomevfs

Most applications, including the gnomevfs headers themselves, expect the files to be under `/usr/include/libgnomevfs`, **but** Ubuntu has them under `/usr/include/gnome-vfs-2.0/libgnomevfs`.

Why? The package I'm referring to is called [libgnomevfs2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/libgnomevfs2-dev).

Inside /usr/include/gnome-vfs-2.0/libgnomevfs/gnome-vfs.h` we find:

```
#include <libgnomevfs/gnome-vfs-acl.h>
#include <libgnomevfs/gnome-vfs-address.h>
#include <libgnomevfs/gnome-vfs-async-ops.h>
#include <libgnomevfs/gnome-vfs-cancellation.h>
...
```

Meaning that even the headers themselves expect the files to be in that location - and nothing that includes this file will work.

Am I missing something, or is this a glitch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package is installed in `/usr/include/gnome-vfs-2.0` so that it can coexist with other versions of gnome-vfs (e.g. imagine also having `/usr/include/gnome-vfs-1.0` available). When a package needs to build against a version of gnome-vfs, it should query `pkg-config` to find the installation location. (This is normally done during `configure` for the to-be-compiled software.) For example:

```
pkg-config --cflags gnome-vfs-2.0
-pthread -DORBIT2=1 -I/usr/include/gnome-vfs-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gnome-vfs-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gconf/2 -I/usr/include/orbit-2.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include
```

Note the use of all the `-I` flags, including `-I/usr/include/gnome-vfs-2.0`. The output of the `pkg-config --cflags` call would normally be added to the `CFLAGS` environment variable of the build. Given the `-I` part, the compiler will be able to find the full path to the headers, since it will start looking in `/usr/include/gnome-vfs-2.0` and then tack on the header path `libgnomevfs/gnome-vfs-acl.h`, which will resolve the correct full file path: `/usr/include/gnome-vfs-2.0/libgnomevfs/gnome-vfs-acl.h`.

So, if the software does not already use `pkg-config`, you can try to pass the variables (`cflags` and `libs`) into the `configure` call:

```
CFLAGS=`pkg-config --cflags gnome-vfs-2.0` LDFLAGS=`pkg-config --libs gnome-vfs-2.0` ./configure
```

Answer (score 2):

Applications should not expect the headers and libs to be in a fixed directory but use *pkg-config* to get the needed parameters, e.g.: `pkg-config --cflags gnome-vfs-2.0`

Comment: But even the headers expect the files to be there. How will that be fixed by using this?

Comment: By adding /usr/include/gnome-vfs-2.0 to the search path for header files.